# How to sort javascript array where first record should be specific and then follow by descending order

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

input array as list object like,  `[{ number: 13.23 , Active: false },{ number: 2.21 , Active: false },{ number: 2.3 , Active: true }]`;

Expected sorted descending order output as, "active" object should be first and all other descending sorted by `numbers` after "active" record.
Tried with below approach but it does not give me active as first entry. this sort the descending by number but active not coming first.

```js
const arr = [{ number: 13.23 , Active: false },{ number: 2.21 , Active: false },{ number: 2.3 , Active: true }];

const customSortActiveShouldBeFirst = function(array) {
  let key = 'number';
  if (array && array.length > 0) {
    return array.sort(function(a, b) {
      var x = a[key];
      var y = b[key];
      return (x['Active'] === true ? 1 : (y - x));
    });
  }
  return array;
};
console.log(customSortActiveShouldBeFirst(arr))
```

Expected output:
Active object to be first in result array and then all entries descending by numbers. like, [{ number: 2.3 , **Active: true** },{ number: 13.23 , Active: false },{ number: 2.21 , Active: false }]

Comment: Can you show the result array that should be in the end?

Comment: Active object to be first in result array and then all entries descending by numbers.  like, `[{ number: 2.3 , Active: True },{ number: 13.23 , Active: false },{ number: 2.21 , Active: false }]`

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to change `True` to `true`

Comment: expected result as sorted by first Active record that is what not coming up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First sort by `Active` then DSC of number when the Active values are same.

```js
const arr = [
  { number: 13.23, Active: false },
  { number: 2.21, Active: false },
  { number: 2.3, Active: true },
];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.Active === b.Active) {
    return b.number - a.number;
  } else if (a.Active || !b.Active) {
    return -1;
  } else if (b.Active || !a.Active) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. Priortise selecting an element if it's active. Then, select whose `number` is greater.

```js
const arr = [{ number: 13.23 , Active: false },{ number: 2.21 , Active: false },{ number: 2.3 , Active: true }];

  arr.sort((a, b)=>{
  if(a.Active && !b.Active){
     return -1
  }else if(!a.Active && b.Active){
     return 1
  } 
  return b.number - a.number //since you want in the descending number. For ascending order a.number - b.number
});

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr = [
    { number: 13.23, Active: false },
    { number: 2.21, Active: false },
    { number: 2.3, Active: true }
]
customSortActiveShouldBeFirst = function (array) {
    let key = 'number';
    if (array && array.length > 0) {
        return array.sort(function (a, b) {
            var x = a[key];
            var y = b[key];
            if (a.Active && b.Active) {
                return y - x;
            }
            if (a.Active) {
                return -1
            }
            if (b.Active) {
                return 1;
            }
            return y - x;
        });
    }
    return array;
};
console.log(customSortActiveShouldBeFirst(arr))
```

Comment: if  a={ number: 2.21, Active: false } , b = { number: 2.3, Active: true }. Your sort callback function would return what? Think about it.

Comment: We were thinking the same :) - you might have two typos, you should probably return ``x - y`` and not ``b - a``?

Comment: Thank you for reminding. We should compare the a's property-Active and number.

Answer (score 1):

You can `filter` by the items of the array which `Active` is `true` and `false`.

Then sort the items of the array which `Active` is `false`

```js
const arr = 
  [
    { number: 13.23 , Active: false },
    { number: 2.21 , Active: false },
    { number: 2.3 , Active: true }
  ];

const activeTrueArr = arr.filter(({ Active }) => Active);
const activeFalseArr = arr.filter(({ Active }) => !Active);

activeFalseArr.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.number < b.number ? 1 : -1;
})

console.log([...activeTrueArr, ...activeFalseArr])
```

Comment: The cost is heavy for simple sort operation in terms of two filters and them joining them all together

Answer (score 1):

What happens if there are two or more that are "active"?

If so, I would sort also these and have all of them before the "inactive" ones (also sorted).

```js
const arr = [{ number: 13.23 , Active: false },{ number: 2.21 , Active: false },{ number: 2.3 , Active: true }, { number: 4.3 , Active: true }];

const customSortActiveShouldBeFirst = function(array) {
  let key = 'number';
  if (array && array.length > 0) {
    return array.sort(function(a, b) {
      if (a['Active'] && b['Active']) return b[key] - a[key];
      if (a['Active']) return -1;
      if (b['Active']) return +1;
      return b[key] - a[key];
    });
  }
  return array;
};
console.log(customSortActiveShouldBeFirst(arr))
```

Output (with one more "active" added to input):

```js
[
  {
    "number": 4.3,
    "Active": true
  },
  {
    "number": 2.3,
    "Active": true
  },
  {
    "number": 13.23,
    "Active": false
  },
  {
    "number": 2.21,
    "Active": false
  }
]
```

---

---

Example to show that @rahul-dwivedi's answer can produce unexpected results (to address the comment that my answer is doing too much):

```js
const arr = [{ number: 13.23 , Active: false },{ number: 2.21 , Active: false },{ number: 2.3 , Active: true }, { number: 14.23 , Active: false }, { number: 1.3 , Active: true }];

arr.sort((a, b)=>{
  if(a.Active && !b.Active){
    return -1
  }
  return b.number - a.number //since you want in the descending number. For ascending order a.number - b.number
});

console.log(arr)
```

Output (of @rahul-dwivedi's answer with example input):

```js
[
  {
    "number": 14.23,
    "Active": false
  },
  {
    "number": 2.3,
    "Active": true
  },
  {
    "number": 1.3,
    "Active": true
  },
  {
    "number": 13.23,
    "Active": false
  },
  {
    "number": 2.21,
    "Active": false
  }
]
```

Comment: It's really not needed to do that much. Check mine. It would take care of these.

Comment: @RahulDwivedi I don't think that is true, see my updated answer, I gave an input to your function that produces the wrong output? (Try your answer with this input ``const arr = [{ number: 13.23 , Active: false },{ number: 2.21 , Active: false },{ number: 2.3 , Active: true }, { number: 14.23 , Active: false }, { number: 1.3 , Active: true }];``)

Comment: Thanks. Updated. Check now

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, your updated answer should now handle all inputs.